# How to encode text with jquery for whatsapp

Tags: jquery, encode, whatsapp

I make whatssap contact form, and i must encode message before post. Whatsapp require this. Check [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/). So i made this form, with jquery keyup function.

It converts message to encoded text for hidden input value. It works. But when i submit `i want to get info...`, in whatsapp message looks like `i%20want%20to%20get%20info...`

I also tried `encodedURI` but it not works too.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".message").keyup(function () {
        var normal = $(this).val(),
            encoded = encodeURIComponent(normal);

        $('.encoded-input').val(encoded);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send" target="_blank">

<input type="text" class="message" value="">

<button type="submit">Send</button>
<input type="hidden" name="text" class="encoded-input" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="4440555">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? what is the error?

Comment: It show like this in whatsapp screen. `i%20want%20to%20get%20info...`